# Heroku Toolbelt: -bash: alias: Added: not found

Tags: macos, bash, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I signed up for Heroku account today and I installed Toolbelt on my Mac (OSX 10.10.1).

When I opened up my Terminal, I get this:

```
Last login: Sun Jan  4 21:50:53 on ttys000
-bash: alias: Added: not found
-bash: alias: by: not found
-bash: alias: the: not found
-bash: alias: Heroku: not found
-bash: alias: Toolbelt: not found
Zulhilmis-MBP:~ zulhilmizainudin$
```

This is my `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin/:$PATH

export PATH=/Applications/android_sdk/tools:$PATH

export ANDROID="/Applications/android_sdk/tools"

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/bin:$PATH

alias php='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/bin/php'### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
```

My questions:

1. How to fixed the `not found` errors inside the Terminal?
2. Is my `.bash_profile` correct? Lately, I've added many new lines inside that file and I've no idea at all about this `.bash_profile` thing. I just did copy paste from web when I got stucked with problems. If it looks wrong, can you please suggest corrections for this `.bash_profile`?

Comment: You only need to export a variable once even if it changes later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your line:

```
alias php='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/bin/php'### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
```

to:

```
alias php="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/bin/php"
### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
```

Your `.bash_profile` looks ok. The only improvement you could do is, to combine all path lines in one, but it is not really that important.

Comment: For example `export PATH="/usr/local/git/bin/:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Applications/android_sdk/tools:$PATH"`

Comment: Just to clarify the problem was that the closing single quote and the comment marker were touching. Simply adding a space there would also have worked. As it was the shell saw the `###` as part of the `php` alias and the other words as alias names to display.